# How do I determine reachability over intranet (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have used AFNetworking and Reachability now and then but it has always been for checking internet connection. How do I tell if the iOS device is connected to a WLAN that has no internet connection?

I have to be able to know reachability status in real time.

*Just a clarification:

I do not want to check if internet is reachable.
I want to check if the device is connected to the WLAN.

*Changed LAN to WLAN to clarify

Comment: You ask for code so as per guidelines you should provide a small SSCCE. Favorited as I don't know this and it sounds useful :)

Comment: How are you pulling off LAN only on iOS? Sounds like the poster is confused.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato, I don't think he means LAN literally (as opposed to WLAN), but instead is looking to test connection on his local network. To me, your answer is perfect. +1.

Comment: If you look at my answer, you will see that the call "isReachableViaWiFi" will check to see if you are connected to a wifi network.

Answer (score 1):

Reachability deals with connections to 2 types of network connections, WWans(cell connection) and WiFi. I am guessing you are talking about being connected via WiFi.

Try something like this:

```
-(BOOL)isWifiRouterConnected
{
    BOOL returnValue = NO;
    //test for a wifi connection
    Reachability *wifiReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
    BOOL wifiReachable = [wifiReachability isReachableViaWiFi];

    //test for connection to google
    if( wifiReachable )
    {
        returnValue = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"google.com"];
    }
    return returnValue;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I should have mentioned that I do not want the result of my reachability test to be affected by connection to internet. This is what I am look for: If device is connected to LAN, return 1. If device is not connected to LAN, return 0.

Comment: You should use YES/NO or TRUE/FALSE instead of 1/0

Comment: he said he only wants to check for LAN

Comment: @Daij-Djan Show me where on the device you can plug in an ethernet cable.

Answer (score 1):

The standard `Reachability` class that everyone uses is very deceptive. It attempts to determine if a host is reachable only by guessing. For example, if you want to know if you are currently able to reach www.google.com, and you call `[Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];` the app never actually "touches" the server to ensure it is turned on, connected, or responding.

What Reachability actually does roughly looks like this:

1. Look up the IP address using current DNS configuration. If DNS cannot be resolved, the host is unreachable.
2. Look at the current state of all known network connections. If they are all down, the host is unreachable.
3. For each network adapter, determine if the destination IP is on the local subnet. If it is, report it as reachable.
4. For each network adapter, determine if a routing path exists to the destination IP. Generally this only looks at the default gateway. If there is a path to the destination IP, report it as reachable.
5. If everything has failed, the host is not reachable.

The problem you are encountering is if you are on WiFi, but the user has not yet agreed to the terms and conditions, as is common at Starbucks, the destination will still be reported as reachable.

The only real way to test network connectivity is to download something. For example, I frequently see Ping/Pong functions and heartbeat files on servers that are for this sole purpose. In this manor you can test not only your Internet, but if the server is functioning as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Network Apps for iPhone OS, Part 1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=207) and [Part 2](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=208).

Do not use Reachability to preflight your connection and just fire your request.

If you insist on using Reachability to test your connection befor you fire a request, use the method described by Jonah and test with your, only internal reachable, hostname.

For example:

```
    // ... 
    if (wifiReachable) {
        returnValue = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"internalserver.example.com"];
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't determine if there is a working internet connection, only if he can connect to a server on his LAN (which might not exist).

Comment: @Jonah.at.GoDaddy OP clearly stated that he doesn't want to check the "internet", just the "intranet".

Comment: Even so, your solution is only good for exactly 1 network. What happens if he takes his phone to his friends house and wants to use his app there? Chances are, his friend won't have a system with host name "internalserver.example.com".